# Problem running Spring Batch Mongodb example

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am running the `Spring Batch` example from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-example-xml-file-to-database/) as it is without changing anything, but when I tried to run the project I am getting following output. Also `MongoDB` does not shows any collection. Please guide me asap what's wrong here.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exit Status : UNKNOWN
```

Also `MongoDB` does not show any collections:

```
> use test
switched to db test
> show collections
system.indexes
>
```

ReportConverter.java

```
package com.mkyong.converter;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.mkyong.model.Report;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.Converter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.MarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.UnmarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamReader;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamWriter;

//http://x-stream.github.io/converter-tutorial.html
public class ReportConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        //we only need "Report" object
        return type.equals(Report.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {

        Report obj = new Report();

        //get attribute
        obj.setId(Integer.valueOf(reader.getAttribute("id")));
        reader.moveDown(); //get date

        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy").parse(reader.getValue());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        obj.setDate(date);
        reader.moveUp();

        reader.moveDown(); //get impression

        String impression = reader.getValue();
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
        Number number = 0;
        try {
            number = format.parse(impression);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        obj.setImpression(number.longValue());

        reader.moveUp();

        reader.moveDown(); //get click
        obj.setClicks(Integer.valueOf(reader.getValue()));
        reader.moveUp();

        reader.moveDown(); //get earning
        obj.setEarning(new BigDecimal(reader.getValue()));
        reader.moveUp();

        return obj;
    }
}
```

database.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd">

    <!-- connect to mongodb -->
    <mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="test" />

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- stored job-meta in database
    <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="databaseType" value="mysql" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />
    -->

    <!-- stored job-meta in memory --> 
    <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />


    <bean id="jobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

JobReport.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">

    <batch:job id="reportJob">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="xmlItemReader" writer="mongodbItemWriter"
                    commit-interval="1">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="mongodbItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemWriter">
        <property name="template" ref="mongoTemplate" />
        <property name="collection" value="report" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="xmlItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
        <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="record" />
        <property name="resource" value="classpath:xml/report.xml" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="reportUnmarshaller" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="reportUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">

        <property name="aliases">
            <util:map id="aliases">
                <entry key="record" value="com.mkyong.model.Report" />

                <!-- 
                <entry key="date" value="java.lang.String" />
                <entry key="impression" value="java.lang.Long" />
                <entry key="clicks" value="java.lang.Integer" />
                <entry key="earning" value="java.math.BigDecimal" />
                 -->
            </util:map>
        </property>

        <property name="converters">
            <array>
                <ref bean="reportConverter" />
            </array>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="reportConverter" class="com.mkyong.converter.ReportConverter" />

</beans>
```

pom.xml:

```
<properties>
        <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.batch.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
        <spring.data.version>1.2.1.RELEASE</spring.data.version>
        <mongodb.driver.version>2.11.2</mongodb.driver.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring XML to/back object -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Batch dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Batch unit test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MongoDB database driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${mongodb.driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run this code by making following changes. Please see code
**pom.xml**

```
<properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.batch.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
        <spring.data.version>1.8.4.RELEASE</spring.data.version>
        <mongodb.driver.version>3.1.1</mongodb.driver.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <jcl.slf4j.version>1.7.12</jcl.slf4j.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring XML to/back object -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Batch dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Batch unit test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MongoDB database driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${mongodb.driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**ReportConverter.java**

```
public class ReportConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        //we only need "Report" object
        return type.equals(Report.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {

        Report obj = new Report();

        //get attribute
        obj.setId(Integer.valueOf(reader.getAttribute("id")));
        reader.moveDown(); //get date

        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(reader.getValue());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        obj.setDate(date);
        reader.moveUp();

        reader.moveDown(); //get impression

        String impression = reader.getValue();
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
        Number number = 0;
        try {
            number = format.parse(impression);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        obj.setImpression(number.longValue());

        reader.moveUp();

        reader.moveDown(); //get click
        obj.setClicks(Integer.valueOf(reader.getValue()));
        reader.moveUp();

        reader.moveDown(); //get earning
        obj.setEarning(new BigDecimal(reader.getValue()));
        reader.moveUp();
        return obj;
    }
}
```

**Report.java**

```
public class Report implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id;
    private Date date;
    private long impression;
    private int clicks;
    private BigDecimal earning;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public long getImpression() {
        return impression;
    }

    public void setImpression(long impression) {
        this.impression = impression;
    }

    public int getClicks() {
        return clicks;
    }

    public void setClicks(int clicks) {
        this.clicks = clicks;
    }

    public BigDecimal getEarning() {
        return earning;
    }

    public void setEarning(BigDecimal earning) {
        this.earning = earning;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");

        return "Report [id=" + id + ", date=" + dateFormatter.format(date) + ", impression=" + impression + ", clicks=" + clicks + ", earning="
                + earning + "]";
    }
}
```

**App.java**

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] springConfig  = 
            {   "spring/batch/config/database.xml", 
                "spring/batch/config/context.xml",
                "spring/batch/jobs/job-report.xml" 
            };

        ApplicationContext context = 
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);

        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean("reportJob");

        try {
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
            System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

**database.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd">

    <!-- connect to mongodb -->
    <mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="yourdb" />

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**context.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- stored job-meta in memory --> 
    <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="jobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**job-report.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">

    <batch:job id="reportJob">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="xmlItemReader" writer="mongodbItemWriter" commit-interval="1">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="mongodbItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemWriter">
        <property name="template" ref="mongoTemplate" />
        <property name="collection" value="report" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="xmlItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
        <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="record" />
        <property name="resource" value="classpath:xml/report.xml" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="reportUnmarshaller" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="reportUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">

        <property name="aliases">
            <util:map id="aliases">
                <entry key="record" value="com.mkyong.model.Report" />
                <!-- 
                <entry key="date" value="java.lang.String" />
                <entry key="impression" value="java.lang.Long" />
                <entry key="clicks" value="java.lang.Integer" />
                <entry key="earning" value="java.math.BigDecimal" />
                 -->
            </util:map>
        </property>

        <property name="converters">
            <array>
                <ref bean="reportConverter" />
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="reportConverter" class="com.mkyong.converter.ReportConverter" />
</beans>
```

report.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<report>
    <record id="1">
        <date>6/1/2013</date>
        <impression>139,237</impression>
        <clicks>40</clicks>
        <earning>220.90</earning>
    </record>
    <record id="2">
        <date>6/2/2013</date>
        <impression>339,100</impression>
        <clicks>60</clicks>
        <earning>320.88</earning>
    </record>
    <record id="3">
        <date>6/3/2013</date>
        <impression>431,436</impression>
        <clicks>76</clicks>
        <earning>270.80</earning>
    </record>
    <record id="4">
        <date>3/12/2016</date>
        <impression>534,987</impression>
        <clicks>43</clicks>
        <earning>454.80</earning>
    </record>
</report>
```

**mongodb.properties**

```
mongo.host=127.0.0.1
mongo.port=27017
mongo.db=yourdb
```